# When run `pip-compile requirements.in` in macOS12 monterey using venv python-3.9.9, pg_config not found

Tags: python, macos, pip-tools

OS: monterey macOSv12.0.1
python venv: 3.9.9

requirements.in

```
# To update requirements.txt, run:
#
#    pip-compile requirements.in
#
# To install in localhost, run:
#
#    pip-sync requirements.txt
#

django==3.2.10  # https://www.djangoproject.com/

psycopg2-binary==2.9.2 # https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2
```

After i turn on venv, then i type `pip-compile requirements.in` then i get a bunch of errors about pg_config not found

This is my asciinema https://asciinema.org/a/sl9MqmrayLAR3rRxEul4mYaxw

I have tried `env LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib' pip-compile requirements.in` but same.

Please advise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I appreciate the other 2 answers from @Vishnudev and @cetver

But I tried to install postgresql using brew install and it took a very long time and I still cannot complete after 20 mins.

I figured this out eventually after much googling

Here are my tech specs of my situation:

1. monterey 12.1.0
2. Apple silicon
3. zsh

### Concepts

Conceptually, what I did is :

1. install openssl, turn on all the exports associated with that,
2. then install libpq, turn on all the exports associated with that,
3. then turn on python venv

Here are my steps I took. It's entirely possible not all steps are needed. But I have limited time so here they are.

### Steps

1. `brew install openssl`
2. put the following in .zshrc `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"`
3. put the following in .zshenv

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

4. `source ~/.zshrc`
5. `brew install libpq`
6. put the following in .zshrc `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"`
7. put the following in .zshenv

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib/pkgconfig"
```

8. `source ~/.zshenv`
9. Turn on venv
10. Now the installing of psycopg2-binary should work

Links that help me:

1. [the one abt openssl](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1200#issuecomment-776159466)
2. [the one abt libpq](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1200#issuecomment-934861409)

Comment: I opted to use a custom script, instead of `.zshenv`, so had to combine the `LDFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS` values (e.g., `export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib"`) to successfully install. `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` was not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install `openssl` using brew

```
brew install openssl
brew install postgres       # If not installed and if required
```

Set the environment variables globally either temporarily by copying the below into the terminal or adding to `.bashrc`

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"
```

You'll also need to set the path for PostgreSQL if not set

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@11/bin:$PATH
```

REMEMBER: Replace @___ with your version

Then proceed with requirements.txt

Comment: why do i have to install postgres? can i get away with not installing postgres? i typically run docker to run my apps. all i want to do is use pip-tools to produce a requirements.txt

Comment: Install only if you run it locally. @KimStacks